# OAuth Request Token and Twitter

Tags: perl, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

Okay, I am trying to use OAuth to access Twitter to be able to get a list of friends from the user logging in. I am writing this in Perl on localhost and using the example seen here:

http://www.commonmap.info/w/index.php/Oauth_perl_examples

The problem that I am having is that I receive this error message in apache logs:

> [Mon May 30 15:29:02 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Parameter oauth_callback_confirmed not valid for a message of type Net::OAuth::RequestTokenResponse line 36

It appears to be having the problem at the line:

```
my $response = Net::OAuth->response('request token')->from_post_body($res->content);
```

I have tried several things and looked all around the web to find a solution but am at a loss. Any help is greatly appreciated and if you need anymore info that I didn't specify just let me know!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the code is expecting an `oauth_callback_confirmed` parameter to be returned from Twitter when there isn't one. `oauth_callback_confirmed` is returned when you specify an `oauth_callback` URL in the request to get the access_token. You can read more about `oauth_callback` on [dev.twitter.com](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth#request-token).

Answer (score 0):

I remember I was having a somewhat similar problem, but it was requiring me to supply a callback. In my case it turned to be a different protocol flavor.
I had to comment out

```
$Net::OAuth::PROTOCOL_VERSION = Net::OAuth::PROTOCOL_VERSION_1_0A;
```

Though in your case it is non-revised version

```
$Net::OAuth::PROTOCOL_VERSION = Net::OAuth::PROTOCOL_VERSION_1_0;
```

Try switching version.